# How to use double to be more secure and precise?

Tags: c++, c, double, overflow, underflow

Statements in each case are mathematically equivalent. My question is which one is better to choose while coding. Which part of code may cause overflow for some ranges of variables, while the other doesn't have overflow for the same ranges. Which part of code is more precise and why?

```
double x, y, z;

//case 1
x = (x * y) * z;
x *= y * z;

//case 2
z = x + x*y;
z = x * ( 1.0 + y);

//case 3
y = x/5.0;
y = x*0.2;
```

Comment: You should read about floating point arithmetics. There is enough information to be found by a simple search.

Comment: If your project needs floating point precision to be maximized by enforcing a certain coding style, then something is likely going wrong.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). `x/5.0` would be more precise because 0.2 can't be represented in binary floating-point but `x*0.2` would be faster

Comment: "...secure due to overflow and underflow issues" This doesn't make sense unless you know how large numbers you are dealing with. Did you mean to ask which lines may have floating point inaccuracy issues?

Comment: For example, `(0.000001 * 100000000) * 10000000` won't cause overflow in my computer while `0.000001 * (100000000 * 10000000)` does. Also I want  to consider the floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: @Mehrshad Suggest appending your comment to the post.

Comment: Ways to deal with `0.000001 * (100000000 * 10000000)`.  1) Take `sqrt()`  of each argument, multiply, then square the result.  (Lose CPU time, lose ~0.5 ULP per multiplication, but range is saved.  2) Extract exponent and scale the arguments to near 1.  Multiple  `a,b,c`.  Sum exponents, apply exponent to product.  (Work, but not CPU expensive, range is absolutely saved and no precision loss).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Case 1
x = (x * y) * z;
x *= y * z;

// Case 2
z = x + x*y;
z = x * ( 1.0 + y);

// Case 3
y = x/5.0;
y = x*0.2;
```

Case 1: `x *= y * z;` is like `x = x * (y * z);` so this case stresses the evaluation order.  Should either sub-product exceed computation range and convert to `INF` or `0.0` or a sub-normal, the final product would significantly be affected depending on order.  OTOH, intermediate math may be performed at a wider FP type.  Search for `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`.  In that case the order could be irrelevant if all computation was done as `long double`.

Case 2: The 2 forms are slightly different. The 2nd is numerically more stable as the addition/subtraction uses exact values: `1, y` versus the first `x, x*y`,  `x*y` potentially being a rounded answer.  Additional/subtraction is prone to draconian precision loss - in this case when `y` is near `-1.0`.  As case 1, wider intermediate math helps, but the 2nd form is still better.

C11 (C99?) offer `fma(double x, double y, double z)` and using `fma(x, y, x)` would be another good alternative.

> The `fma` functions compute `(x × y) + z`, rounded as one ternary operation: they compute the value (as if) to infinite precision and round once to the result format, according to the current rounding mode. A range error may occur.

Case 3:

The "trick" here is `double 0.2` the same as mathematical 0.2?  Typically it is not - yet they are close.  Yet an optimizing compile could 1 ) treat them as the same or 2) or as in case 1, use wider math.  Then the result is the same for both lines of code.

Otherwise: depending on rounding mode, the two forms may exhibit a difference in the lest bit (ULP).  With a weak compiler, recommend `/5.0`

Division by 5.0 *is* more accurate than multiplication by an approximate 0.2.  But coded either way, a smart compiler may use do a wide multiplication for both.

Comment: I didn't get why you said `x * ( 1.0 + y )` is more precise than `x + x*y )` the first one uses approximate values `x*y` and `x`, while the second one uses the approximate values `x`, `y`, `1.0 + y`

Comment: In my GCC 4.9.2 when I chose variables `x = 1000000` and `y = 0.001`, and the results were `x * ( 1.0 + y ) = 1000999.999...` and `x + x*y = 1001000`

Comment: @Mehrshad `x` is not an approximate value, it is an argument to the equation.  For error analysis, arguments to the equation/function are assumed exact.  The product `x*y` is not an argument, but an intermediate result that may not be exact.  Addition/subtraction is far more sensitive to inexact arguments than multiplication/division.  So doing the `+` first with exact augments results in a more precise answer than `*` first.

Comment: @Mehrshad tried your test values and with various code, the 2 approaches were within 1.0 ULP of each other.  Tried same test with `y near -1.0` and the `x * (1.0 + y)` remained close to the correct answer, whereas `x + x*y` lost significant precision – losing 6 decimal digits of accuracy with `y = -1 + 1e6`.  It is not a question of which approach gives the “right” answer most often.  Both work about the same for most numbers.  But `y near -1.0`,  `x + x*y` gives significant inferior result.  `x * (1.0 + y)` does not have such a hole.

Comment: Generalization:  Largest precession lost involves addition/subtraction where the results nearly cancels out.  Largest range problem occurs with chains of multiplication/division in the same absolute direction toward 0 or `INF`.